# Problema al verificar valores SQL con WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server, sql

tengo este problema en SQL Server 2008. He creado una tabla para ingresar datos y que luego el usuario vea los que planea ingresar (en una carga masiva con archivo csv).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.temp_horario2 (
idTempHorario INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
idEmpleado VARCHAR(500),
nroDocumento VARCHAR(500),
dia VARCHAR(500),
idHorario VARCHAR(500),
idUsuario INT
);
```

En principio varias de esas columnas no deben ser VARCHAR, sino INT, pero estan VARCHAR para que luego en una vista de tabla temporal el usuario vea los datos que ingreso y se le indique cuales están mal. El problema es al comparar los valores insertados de esta tabla con las tablas originales, ya que esos si son INT. Al probar estos datos insertados:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.temp_horario2 (idEmpleado, nroDocumento, dia, idHorario, idUsuario) VALUES (12, 3224, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.temp_horario2 (idEmpleado, nroDocumento, dia, idHorario, idUsuario) VALUES (2123, 10782295, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.temp_horario2 (idEmpleado, nroDocumento, dia, idHorario, idUsuario) VALUES (234324234, 3232495, 34, 2, 34);
INSERT INTO dbo.temp_horario2 (idEmpleado, nroDocumento, dia, idHorario, idUsuario) VALUES ('asdf', 2, 'dsf', 'dos', 34);
```

Me salen estos errores:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Error de conversión al convertir el
>   valor varchar 'asdf' al tipo de datos smallint.

o

> La conversión del valor varchar '234324234' ha desbordado una columna
>   INT2. Utilice una columna de tipo integer mayor.

Este es el query con columnas que me sirven para validar los datos.

```
SELECT th.idTempHorario, th.idEmpleado, th.nroDocumento, th.dia, th.idHorario, th.idUsuario,
CASE
    WHEN th.idEmpleado IN(SELECT rhem.idEmpleado FROM rrhh.dbo.Empleado AS rhem) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS validacionIdEmpleado,
CASE
    WHEN th.nroDocumento IN(SELECT rhem.numTipoDocuIdent FROM rrhh.dbo.Empleado AS rhem) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS validacionNroDocumento,
CASE
    WHEN th.dia IN(SELECT gd.idDia FROM General.dbo.dia AS gd) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS validacionDia,
CASE
    WHEN th.idHorario IN(SELECT rhas.idHorarioAdmin FROM rrhh.asistencia.horarioAdmin AS rhas) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS validacionIdHorario
FROM database.dbo.temp_horario2 AS th
```

Comment: Los mensajes de error son claros. En el primero estarías intentando guardar el valor `asdf` en una columna del tipo `smallint` y en el segundo estarías intentando guardar el valor `234324234` en una columna con un tamaño inferior a ese valor. Esto se resuelve normalizando tu archivo `.csv`, si no quieres tener un desastre de datos. Cuando vas a usar un CSV para guardar en tu BD debes estar seguro de que cada valor del mismo corresponde con la columna de destino. Los dos mensajes de error indican que no es así.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero no estoy insertando datos así. En la columna donde estoy ingresando strings como 'asdf', etc., son del tipo VARCHAR, el error me lo da al comparar ese dato con otro que es string, porque lo transforma. Lo que yo quería saber es si hay una forma de comparar esos datos VARCHAR con los originales que si son INT para que devuelva el valor 0 o 1 de valido en cada CASE del query.

Comment: Puedo insertar normalmente esos datos porque la tabla temporal que he creado esta con columnas VARCHAR, lo que quiero es como solucionar el error al comparar esos datos VARCHAR con otros INT Y que en caso de ser iguales me den el valor 1 y si no el valor 0 como estan en el CASE statement del query.

Comment: No veo en tu código ningún intento de conversión y el planteamiento de la pregunta es algo confuso. ¿Puedes decirnos dónde ocurren los mensajes de error (en cuál de las consultas que muestras en la pregunta)? Y ¿qué significan entonces las inserciones ya que dices que no estás intentando insertar esos datos?

Comment: Por otra parte, si las columnas son `VARCHAR` tu consulta debe poner los valores rodeados por comillas simples, algo así: **`INSERT INTO dbo.temp_horario2 (idEmpleado, nroDocumento, dia, idHorario, idUsuario) VALUES ('2123', '10782295', '1', '1', '1');`**

Comment: Ya esta, tenia que transformar los valores obtenidos en los case statemente así.

IN(SELECT CAST(rhem.idEmpleado AS VARCHAR) FROM rrhh.dbo.Empleado AS rhem) THEN 1